# Next js 14 App router: What is the mechanism through which Client component able to call Server Actions

Tags: next.js, server-action

At first glance I under the impression that `Server Actions` are just function written on server, to be executed on the server by some other server code or Server Component.

[image]from [NextJs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns)

To my surprise, `Server Action` can also be called by the Client component (maked as `'use client'`).
This has left me all confused. How can an server function be called by a code running on browser? Seems like I am missing something. I couldn't find anything online about it.

So my question is:
How is Client component (browser code) able to call `Server Actions` (server code)? Would love to see some write up or a reference?

Comment: have you watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bugO1tmSDpM&pp=ygUvc2VydmVyIGFjdGlvbnMgdnMgY2xpZW50IGNvbXBvbmVudHMgcGl5dXNoIGdhcmc%3D) yet? it might clear your doubts.

Comment: and also [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W83jTvvqzg) as its even more related.

Comment: @deadcoder0904 Thanks for response. But neither of videos answer *how* Client component is able to call server action. They just show an example of it.

Comment: i read somewhere that the naming is unfortunate. client components are not in fact like client-side libraries. you might be assuming that because client is in the name, it might be running on client but it doesn't. see if [these](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/react-jsx-as-a-server-side-templating-language) [4](https://overreacted.io/how-does-the-development-mode-work/) [blogs](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/server-components/) [help](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/) as i haven't fully dove deep into rsc just yet as i'm currently switching to remix.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for a technical explanation rather than a code sample, here is a sufficiently detailed text on the topic from one of the core Next.js devs: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/54075 (look under `The mutations I trigger` > `Invalidation` > `Server Actions (revalidatePath / revalidateTag)` > `How it works`).

Even though it largely describes Server Actions in the context of caching and cache invalidation, this is probably the best source I found on the topic overall.

I'm going to copy the most relevant parts here, just in case something happens to that discussion.

> - `"use server"` adds a marker to the function at compile time and move it into a separate module. All Server Actions have their own
>   unique ID so that they can be referred to individually. (This
>   explanation is heavily simplified, reality is a bit more involved)
> - When you call the function it will do a POST request to the current URL with the Server Action ID, that allows Next.js to call the right
>   underlying function.
>
>   - Example of calling the function: The `<form action={serverAction}>` is submitted or you manually call `serverAction()` in a client component
> - While calling the function you’ve defined to be a Server Action a few things can happen
>
>   - [...]
>   - The function returns a result
>
>     - You can return your own response from Server Actions, this could be an object, but could also be JSX, anything valid to be serialized
>       from Server Component to Client Component is also a valid return value
>       for Server Actions.
>     - [...]
>     - In order to use the result you have to manually call the Server Action, this does not apply to passing the Server Action directly to
>       the `action` prop in `<form action={serverAction}>`

Answer (score -1):

Client Components, despite the unfortunate naming, does not run only on the browser. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

As mentioned [here](https://makerkit.dev/blog/tutorials/nextjs13),

> Despite their name, "client components" (which, IMHO, is unfortunate) are also server-rendered, and they run on both the server and the client.

I found these 2 videos that explain the concept well [from the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76315942/6141587) recommended by StackOverflow AI:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O94ESaJtHtM
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hD11c2mrq6Q

Comment: Client Components is correct naming. And client component *only* run on browser.  [this](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/server-components/#introduction-to-react-server-components-3) blog you posted got it wrong in the image but got right in the text. Server component can run on both browser on server and on the browser depending on how its imported.

Comment: @sandeepgupta lol no dude. you are misinterpreting it. those guys know how react works as they have a wide audience. they are not wrong. read https://makerkit.dev/blog/tutorials/nextjs13 & see the statement which i mentioned i read somewhere `Despite their name, "client components" (which, IMHO, is unfortunate) are also server-rendered, and they run on both the server and the client.` do not skim. actually read them to understand. also, read https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-react-server-components/ it will take you a whole day to go through all the links but you'll get it finally.

Comment: read the first line [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components). Happy to be proven wrong if you show official docs OR show a running code.

Comment: @sandeepgupta the guys i've linked to have 5-10 years of experience & understand react inside out but you're free to believe whatever you want even though its clearly wrong. i can easily tell you've not even read/watched anything i've linked. for starters, if client component were only rendered on client side, then in the network tab the requests would go through xhr tab. but it doesn't. watch the [2nd video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W83jTvvqzg) (15mins) i've linked of piyush garg. it literally shows you the exact code you want.

Comment: May be we disagree on definitions. Let me clarity. A server component (that is, any component without "use client") will be executed on browser if its imported inside client component (that is, any component with "use client" or any of its Imported children of "use client" component or their children and so on ...). Here imported means use of "import ..." and not the component which is coming via prop/children. These "server components" are *used as*  "client component" and executed on browser, hence you see network request on network tab. Thats what is being shown in your 2nd video.

Comment: there is no disagreement on definitions because its not our definitions. the definitions are by react teams because server components (sc) & client components (cc) are a react feature, not a next.js feature. sc gets executed on server. cc get executed on both server/client. you can render a server component inside a client component shown in 2nd video. dont make up your own definitions. just use the react's one. your question answers itself when you realize cc also renders on server so they can call server actions there. rsc is complicated so i recommend going through all the links in 1 day.

Comment: see [if this article](https://scastiel.dev/simplest-example-server-actions-nextjs) answers your question. that's all i got. i hope you go through rsc first, then re-read what i said once you've been through it so you finally understand what i was saying. good luck. i think that piyush guy has a course on next.js which you might wanna take since he explains everything easily using analogies. bonus point: he uses hindi which makes it easier for me than english. not that i'm terrible at english but his explanations are golden. at least. they were in the 1-hour docker video.

Comment: This is incorrect. Client components are not "run" on the server. You seem to insist on appealing to a cherry-picked authority to prove your point, so I'm not going to quote the docs and instead leave this reference to the source code:  https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/dc3178151b8cb0359e5c36b8ed57458b807ae8e3/packages/react-server/src/ReactFlightServer.js#L633
As you can see, client components are serialized as React.Lazy and are not run.

Comment: @deadcoder0904 you are too rude for a person who knows so little. I have only been trying to be nice, as people are generally nice on this site. I only asked you to show official docs or running code. We aren't discussing religion here. Show me code and I will accept I am wrong. Why did you assume i didnt watch videos?? I have watched both and its infact you who has misunderstood. I even explained to you how you misunderstood, but you completely ignored that. In any case, none of that has anything do with my question.

Comment: @shkaper the point i was making is client components are not just run on the client side browser which is what the op was insisting. re-read his question again. see this line `How is Client component (browser code) able to call Server Actions (server code)? Would love to see some write up or a reference?` so i said i've read they are not just run on client side browser. i haven't even dove deep into cc & sc but all i know is cc isn't run just on the browser. its not 1 cherry-picked source. seen it multiple times just linked once.

Comment: @sandeepgupta dude where was i being rude? can you point me? you are being rude by saying i know too little. i didnt make an assumption. if you had read what i linked, it is written there on the first few lines. i pointed you to the right direction but you were insisting it is not correct. i've linked to multiple high-authority people but you are the one saying they are wrong. again, tell me who is wrong? if you read my answer above, i've specifically written `Please correct me if I'm wrong.` because i know little about the topic but remembered the line i quoted.

Comment: @deadcoder0904 Sorry, I still don't see how `client components are not just run on the client side browser` could explain the ability of client components to call server actions _in the browser_. Even if that statement was true - which it is not, or at least very misleading. Your answer seems to imply that when the client component calls the server action, it somehow makes the server render the tree (including the client component), call the actual server action code internally, serialize the resulting tree and pass it back to the client. This is simply not how it works.

Comment: @shkaper `<ClientComponent><ServerComponent/></ClientComponent>` code works if [you see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W83jTvvqzg&pp=ygUScGl5dXNoIGdhcmcgbmV4dGpz) which you can read subtitles if its not english but you can see the code & network tab. if it was just run on client side as you are saying, shouldn't it throw error above? earlier, next.js used to throw error if you used node modules on client. now i'm wrapping `ServerComponent` inside `ClientComponent` as children so it shouldnt work if it was only rendered on client. i guess my cherrypicked blog was right after all.

Comment: @deadcoder0904 No, you're again inferring wrong things from observing the behaviour. Read this to understand why this works: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#supported-pattern-passing-server-components-to-client-components-as-props. `With this approach, <ClientComponent> and <ServerComponent> are decoupled and can be rendered independently. In this case, the child <ServerComponent> can be rendered on the server, well before <ClientComponent> is rendered on the client.`

Comment: @deadcoder0904 You're assuming that server-side React has to render  ClientComponent before it knows it has to render ServerComponent, but this assumption is wrong.

Comment: @shkaper no, i'm not saying anything about technicalities bcz idk much about this nor interested in it. my point was again related to op's question & you saying that `ClientComponent` is just rendered on client. but if you set a timeout for 10 secs in `ServerComponent`, `ClientComponent` waits for 10 secs. imo it should either throw an error or it shouldnt wait 10 secs to prove that it runs just on client for both of your statements to be true. anyways, i'll take a closer look at it when i need this which is probably not soon. thanks for the discussion.